# How to select html.dropdownlist value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have one view page consists of few dropdownlist and these are filled by database. The form creates a frame. When I try to edit that frame the values are getting selected.

View page:

```
 <%: Html.DropDownList("ProductGroup", ViewBag.ProductGroup as SelectList, "Select Product Group",new { @class="ddl"})%>
```

In controller:

```
ViewBag.ProductGroup = new SelectList(
    getcategories
        .Where(x => x.option_type == Constant.ProductGroup)
        .ToList(), 
    "option_name", 
    "option_name", 
    data.product_group
);
```

Comment: Need help urgently. Thanks

Comment: This is asp.net? You should edit your question to add this information. Also include more code.

Comment: I don't undestand what is your problem? The last param in constructor for class SelectList is used to set current value.

Comment: Very vague question. Try adding some meat to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Laxmi, it looks like you are setting ‘selected value’ for the lists in two places. First you set ‘selected value’ when you create the select list at the controller and then you set it at the view.

Could you try removing one of them please? I would suggest removing it from the controller, so your controller code would be ;

```
ViewBag.ProductGroup = new SelectList(
    getcategories
        .Where(x => x.option_type == Constant.ProductGroup)
        .ToList(), 
    "option_name", 
    "option_name"
);
```

Another observation; try to move away from ViewBag as it won’t offer you any compile time type checking and may cause you to do more work if you plan on building unit tests to test the controller actions. Use a simple model instead

Hope this helps